# Angular - How to hide and show content with a boolean for 'this' item in a ngFor loop

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ng-if

I have an ngFor loop displaying several list items. Each list item contains a title. It also contains an input with the title inside it which I want hidden. When I hit an edit button, I want the input for that selected item to show, none of the others. What's the best way to approach this?

Below is what I have so far. However, when initiating 'editItem' and setting 'editable' to true, the input box for all items appears, not just the one I clicked on.

```js
editable = false;

editItem(){
  this.editable = true;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of items | async">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="title"> {{ item.item_title }}</div>
      <input #newItemName type="text" [(ngModel)]="this.item.item_title" *ngIf="editable"/>
      <i aria-hidden="true" (click)="editItem()"></i>
     </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: this would be a good place to abstract out the list items into a separate component. if you do that then your code will work.

Comment: Best way would be retrieve the list of items in your TS. Add `editable` field to each item on the client side `items.forEach(item => item['editable'] = false)` then `*ngIf="item.editable"`

Comment: It's simple but provide a UI example!  input/s and edit button/s.
How are these working?
Edit button appears appears only for the selected element? How is the element selected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can fix it easily *^^*

**typescript**

```
editItem(item: any){
  item.editable = true;
}
```

**html**

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of items | async">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="title"> {{ item.item_title }}</div>
      <input #newItemName type="text" [(ngModel)]="this.item.item_title" *ngIf="item.editable"/>
      <i aria-hidden="true" (click)="editItem(item)"></i>
     </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What an elegant solution. Thank you. I'll this as the answer the moment I'm able to. As a quick follow up: this solution shows the input for the selected item, if I then select another item, is it possible to hide all others (that have already been opened?)

Answer (score 1):

You can.. create an editMode boolean, and array of editStates booleans (one for each item)
in component.ts

```
editMode = false;
editable = new Array<boolean>(this.items.length);
```

Then convert function to set all to false, and edit

- on click event: editItem, feed it the index (so in your `ngFor` loop add `let i = index`) item, and set use quick false fill array followed by index of choice to true.
- on hoverout exit event: exitEditMode.

```
  editItem(index: number) {
    this.editMode = true;
    this.editable.fill(false);
    this.editable[index] = true;
  }

  exitEditMode() {
    this.editMode = false;
  }
```

Then in the html, you can use ngIf to hide all editables that are disabled in edit mode, by probing for editMode and editable selected.
Something like this:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of items | async; let i = index">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="title"> {{ item.item_title }}</div>
      <input #newItemName type="text" [(ngModel)]="this.item.item_title" *ngIf="editable"/>
      <i aria-hidden="true" *ngIf="editMode && editable[i]" (click)="editItem(i)" (mouseout)="exitEditMode()"></i>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```